# how does this check statement works in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How does this function works **logically**? is there any simpler version of this code i can get for better **understanting**.

```
togglePersonHandler =()=>{

  const doesshow = this.state.showPerson;
  this.setState({showPerson : !doesshow});

}
```

Comment: It's just grabbing from the component classes state and setting it to equal the opposite of what the value is, a 1 liner of it is `this.setState({showPerson : !this.state.showPerson});`

Comment: If you're learning React and haven't encountered states before, take a look here: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: @Sasha your first statement is correct if variable is a boolean, if it is a non empty string it will always return false

Comment: check this : https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Comment: @Nico true, I imagine that since the code uses both ! and a `show` in the variable name, I'm assumng it's a bool

Comment: @Faisal Nadeem  check Sasha comment and my link, that the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
togglePersonHandler =()=>{
    const doesshow = this.state.showPerson;
    this.setState({showPerson : !doesshow});
}
```

Your code can be written as the following. We are setting the new state, using the `setState` call, using the values in the `previousState`.
We get the previous value of `showPerson` and 'reverse' the truth value using the [negation `!` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

```
togglePersonHandler = () => {
    this.setState((previousState) => {
         return {
             showPerson : !previousState.showPerson
         }
    });
}
```

[This is the recommended format to write `setState` calls that depend on the previous state.](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

**Truth Table**

This is how the negation operator affects a boolean value, [shown in a truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table)

```
----------------------------
| showPerson | !showPerson |
----------------------------
|    True    |     False   |
----------------------------
|    False   |     True    |
----------------------------
```